# Создание объекта FormData только с нужными полями

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется форма с полями:

```
<form id="form-id">
Логин: <br>
<input name="login" type="text"/>
Пароль: <br>
<input name="pd" type="password"/>
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="Вход" />
</form>
```

Нужно отправить ajax'ом определенные поля формы(форму привёл для наглядности, на самом деле форма гораздо сложнее).

Можно ли на стороне js создать объект `FormData()` заполнив его только нужными полями из формы?
Или допустим, заполнить объект полной формой, типа `FormData(form)` но как то выбрать из объекта только те поля которые нужны для отправки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта решения:

1) Взять все данные с формы и удалить ненужные:

```
var $data = {};
$('#myForm').find ('input, textearea, select').each(function() {
    $data[this.name] = $(this).val();
});

delete data.password;
```

2) Или взять только те данные которые нужны

```
var data = {
    login: $('[name=login]').val(),
    password: $('[name=password]').val()
};
```